# webpack bundle vendor separate from app scripts

Tags: webpack, bundle

I am trying to bundle vendor scripts like jquery separate from my app scripts using webpack.

After bundle my jquery still is not available on one page.

Im not trying to do anything fancy yet just trying to get a hang of webpack.

here is my code

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./scripts/main.js",
        vendor: ["jquery"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./wwwroot/[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js' })
    ]

}
```

Comment: jQuery is always a pain when it comes with webpack. Could you share how you import it inside your project? You just do `import $ from 'jquery'`?

Comment: @Ematipico you know what. i completely didnt import jquery in any of my scripts, thats why it didnt work. 
so simple yet so tricky :))
all i had to do is require and thats all.